# Handling error cases with scp and sshpass

Tags: c, ssh, scp, sshpass

I am trying to implement command line interface command for file transfer and that will call internally

> sshpass -p "password" scp -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -r user@remote-machine:/home/QA.txt /home/faadmin/

Here error handling is not happening properly , when I am running this command using `system()`.if in case route not there for file transfer ,or file not found errors some time they  blocking the execution of CLI command.so  I have check return values after executing the above Linux command not showing  other than 0 and 1.how can I get other return values?

Comment: What do you mean by *"system function"*? `system()`? Are you writing C code?

Comment: Yeah that is c system function to execute Linux commands

Answer (score 0):

You should use `popen()` because `system()` return value tell you if the command has been executed or not. E.G.:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
FILE *output = NULL;
char text[2048];
char cmd[256];

sprintf(cmd, "%s", "sshpass -p \"password\" scp -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -r user@remote-machine:/home/QA.txt /home/faadmin/");

output = popen(cmd, "r");

while(fgets(text, 1024, output) != NULL)
  printf("%s", text);

pclose(output);
}
```